# How to change font color in eclipse for debug popup?

Tags: eclipse, debugging, fonts

does anyone can help me to change the color in eclipse.
I have tried all possibilities and nothing works.

This happens in debug mode. I can't see the details as they are pale grey. 
I am trying to change the font color

[image]

I have ubuntu 10.4 system

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution from the following link:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/45001/how-to-fix-black-tooltips-in-eclipse